# Trying to use a remotely hosted XML file for settings

Tags: c#, xml, class, xml-parsing, application-settings

Apologies for the newbie question, I'm only on day 2 of my adventures with C#...

I'm trying to use a remotely hosted XML file to retrieve some basic settings for my program. I've managed to get it to download and parse the XML file into string variables, but I cannot work out how to make these variables available to the rest of my program.

Here is the code:

```
    public static void getSetting()
    {
        try
        {
            XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
            xml.Load("http://www.domain.com/s/settings.xml");
            XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/Settings/Setting");
            string strEnabled = ""; string strPort = "";
            string strPac = ""; string strRules = ""; string strUpdateUrl = "";

            foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
            {
                strEnabled = xn["Enabled"].InnerText;
                strPort = xn["Port"].InnerText;
                strPac = xn["Pac"].InnerText;
                strRules = xn["Rules"].InnerText;
                strUpdateUrl = xn["UpdateUrl"].InnerText;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unable to download settings: " + e);
        }
    }

    public static void useSettings()
    {
        //use the settings in here
    }
```

I'd also appreciate any critique on my code as I'm still getting to grips with everything and realise that I'm probably not going about this the best way.

Comment: Your problem really doesn't have anything to do with XML - it's all about variable scope. If you want to remember the value of a variable outside a method, then it needs to be a *field* - either static (to be part of the state of the type) or not (to be part of the state of a specific object).

Comment: declare the variables outside the scope of the getting Method in the top of the class somewhere... Declare them as Public or Static or Private.. initialize them to string.Empty; I would also read up on `Variable Scope` and what takes `precedence` meaning if you declare the same variable locally vs globally here is a good link to keep handy until you become more familiar [Variable and Method Scope in Microsoft .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx)